# Installed packages goes to the wrong folder in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I typed `pip install Django` into the pycharm terminal and it installed the Django files to python311\lib\site-packages, an excluded directory, instead of python311\site-packages.

Comment: Pip writes where it is configured to. PyCharm often create you a venv for your project, such that it is isolated from the rest of your system (and your other projects). An "excluded" directory in PyCharm just means it won't get indexed (you won't have search results for its files). Why is that a problem that it got installed there ?

Comment: I can't import packages installed into that directory, when I move the files to the actually site-packages directory the import works. Its quite annoying to move the files manually every time.

Comment: Then it seems your venv was badly configured. Have you tried destroying it and recreating one from scratch (possibly using PyCharm) ?

Comment: I just tried it, it worked, thanks!